# Install ubuntu 16.04 on WSL?

Tags: 16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am interested in running Ubuntu 16.04 on Windows Subsystem for Linux, as it is required for a certain build environment. All that I can find on Microsoft Store is 18.04 and 20.04. Is there a way I can install from iso potentially?

Comment: WSL is a proprietary hypervisor made by Microsoft. We don't get to see the innards, so we don't know what's possible on it. Suggest you use a well-documented virtualization solution like VMWare or VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual) for instructions regarding how to manually download Windows Subsystem for Linux distro packages that aren't in the Microsoft store (this includes Ubuntu 16.04).

As @user535733 pointed out in the comments, WSL is a proprietary service created by Microsoft. Therefore, you will be able to do more by either using a [virtual machine](https://brb.nci.nih.gov/seqtools/installUbuntu.html) (VMWare or VirtualBox) or by [dual booting](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) Ubuntu with your existing windows installation.